# How to write triggers to insert the data from one table to another table which are in different host servers?

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have one table created in a SQL Server database which is in my local server and it gets updated with the data continuously. How to  write a trigger to insert the same data to another SQL Server database which is in Azure Cloud? The important thing is that the two databases are in different servers one is in local and another is in Azure.

Comment: Try Linked Server approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by prefixing the table with the database name. For example, the trigger in db1 can run something like "INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.TableName(column1, column2)....". But in your case you must have the server where you are maintaining the audit table as a a Linked Server to your base table.

However, I would not recommend this. Cross server or cross database triggers may be little risky. If the other database is not available or busy, it can delay or abort your transactions.

I would recommend replication or an asynchronous trigger using Service broker for this type of requirements. 
Here is a link for the process to use Service Broker for asynchronous triggers. 
http://www.madeiradata.com/service-broker-asynchronous-triggers/